# Apply two functions to a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples containing information in the following form as so:

```
carDatabase :: [Car]
carDatabase = [("Ford", "Focus", 2003, [("Autotrader", 9995), ("Parkers", 9495), ("Motors", 9995)]), ("Vauxhall", "Corsa", 2005, [("Autotrader", 5995), ("FOW", 7000), ("Gumtree", 6500)]), ...]
```

And what I am trying to do is `map` this list to return a list of strings with the first element of each tuple (I have a function that does this with `carMan (x,_,_,_) = x)` but also using the `toLower` function and I cannot work out a way to combine them, be it with function compositions or mapping a map etc.

This is the closest I've got.

```
mapTest :: [Car] -> [String]
mapTest cs = map toLower (map carMan cs)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the error I get with:

```
mapTest :: [Car] -> [String]
mapTest cs = map (toLower . carMan) cs

Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: Char -> String
      Actual type: Char -> Char
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘toLower’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(toLower . carMan)’

cars.hs:197:37:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: [(Char, String, Int, [(String, Int)])]
      Actual type: [Car]
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘cs’
    In the expression: map (toLower . carMan) cs
```

Comment: That should work, assuming `carMan` and `toLower` have correct types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with function composition using `.`

```
map ((map toLower) . carMan) cs
```

Or make it a helper function:

```
strLower :: String -> String
strLower = map toLower

mapTest :: [Car] -> [String]
mapTest = map (strLower . carMan)
```

Comment: This is something I tried but the program won't compile with the function like this.

Comment: Can you show that error?

Comment: I see, it appears you are using the `toLower` from `Data.Char`, so that function works only for `Char`, whereas the first item from your `Car` data type is a `String`, which is a *list* of `Char`. You can map `toLower` across the string, or write that as a helper function. See my update.

Comment: Perfect. That's what solves it!